# How can I encrypt a file with private key when I click a button in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am new to JavaFX and cryptography. In this project I need to select a file with file chooser and encrypt it with private key. I have 2 buttons;chooseFileBtn and sendFileBtn. When I click chooseFileBtn, I choose a file and then with clicking sendFileBtn, it should encrypt it with private key. I tried this code below but I got some errors.

Controller:

```
package com.example.demo1;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.stage.FileChooser;

import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;

public class HelloController {
    @FXML
    private Label chooseFileBtn;

    @FXML
    private Label sendFileBtn;

    @FXML
    private ListView listView;

    File selectedFile;

    @FXML
    public void chooseFileButtonClick(ActionEvent event) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, InvalidKeySpecException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchPaddingException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        FileChooser fc = new FileChooser();
        File selectedFile = fc.showOpenDialog(null);

        if( selectedFile != null)
        {
            listView.getItems().add(selectedFile.getPath());
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("File is now valid");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void sendFileButtonClick(ActionEvent event)throws Exception{

        KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        generator.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
        PrivateKey privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
        PublicKey publicKey = pair.getPublic();

        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("private.key")) {
            fos.write(privateKey.getEncoded());
        }
        File privateKeyFile = new File("private.key");
        byte[] privateKeyBytes = Files.readAllBytes(privateKeyFile.toPath());
        KeyFactory keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
        keyFactory.generatePublic(privateKeySpec);

        byte[] fileBytes = Files.readAllBytes(selectedFile.toPath());

        Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        byte[] encryptedFileBytes = encryptCipher.doFinal(fileBytes);

        try (FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(selectedFile)) {
            stream.write(encryptedFileBytes);
        }
    }
}
```

fxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="327.0" prefWidth="323.0" spacing="20.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/17.0.2-ea" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="com.example.demo1.HelloController">
    <padding>
        <Insets bottom="20.0" left="20.0" right="20.0" top="20.0" />
    </padding>
   <children>
      <Label prefHeight="127.0" prefWidth="276.0" text="File Transfer Application">
         <font>
            <Font name="American Typewriter" size="23.0" />
         </font>
      </Label>
      <Button fx:id="chooseFileBtn1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#chooseFileButtonClick" text="Choose A File" />
      <ListView fx:id="listView" prefHeight="28.0" prefWidth="283.0" />
      <Button fx:id="sendFileBtn1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#sendFileButtonClick" text="Send The File" />
   </children>
    
</VBox>
```

Errors:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException
```

Why do I get these errors and how can I fix it?

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the exception?

Comment: For encryption, a *public* key is required. A *private* key is used to sign (or decrypt).

Comment: What do you want to achieve? If you want to create a signature, there are dedicated Java classes for that ([`Signature`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/security/Signature.html)). Regarding the import of the private key (if it is available as DER encoded PKCS#8 key) you must use `PKCS8EncodedKeySpec` and `KeyFactory#generatePrivate()`.

Comment: Yes, I want to create a digital signature

Comment: *Yes, I want to create a digital signature* Are you sure? If so, your question is wrong - digital signatures are really nothing to do with "encryption"

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the actual issue with your code is (I didn't try to debug it).  But your code is pretty close to what you need.

I implemented some basic crypto functions in the JavaFX sample app below and it worked fine for me (OpenJDK 19 + JavaFX 19, OS X 13).  It doesn't use file operations, so it is not exactly what you are trying to implement.  Perhaps try it and check that it works in your environment, then compare the implementation to yours and change what you need to solve your exact problem.

[image: encryptanddecrypt]

Study:

- https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2123/rsa-encryption-with-private-key-and-decryption-with-a-public-key

and some other external crypto resources, to better understand the subject field.

There is some jargon and terms in this solution, if you don't understand any of them, run some independent research.

The example encrypts with a public key and decrypts with a private key because, generally, that makes more sense for most operations as noted in the linked question.  There is no technical issue in encrypting with a private key and decrypting with a public key (it works, you can try it by modifying the sample code), it just makes less sense to do so.

If you encrypt with the private key, the encrypted text can only be decrypted with the public key, but the public key is public, so anybody could have that and anybody could decrypt the file.  This is why such encryption and decryption techniques are used as a step in signature generation and verification, rather than encryption of text for confidentiality.  By comparison, if you encrypt with the public key and decrypt with the private key, only somebody with whom the private key has been shared can decrypt the text, thus confidentiality is preserved.

The example also just straight-up encrypts and decrypts the file with the RSA pair.  Often in an actual application, a [more complex approach is used](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:PGP_diagram.svg).  The asymmetric key might be used to encrypt a symmetric key which is actually used to encrypt or decrypt the document text (or password-based encryption, PBE may be used).  The encrypted symmetric key may or may not be stored in the encrypted document together with some packaging metadata in ASN.1 notation describing the algorithms (name, cipher mode, padding method, etc) used in encrypting the document.  For instance in a [PKCS 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_7) or [PKCS 12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12) or [PGP encrypted](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy) format.  Demonstration of these more complex cases is beyond the scope of this answer.

*Crypto.java*

Generates a new RSA key in the constructor.

The algorithm used and keysize are hardcoded, in an actual app, you would make such information configurable.

The encryption block and padding settings are left as default for the algorithm rather than being explictly provided.

UTF-8 is used as the character encoding for the translation of plain text to and from bytes.

You will want to save the private key if you wish to be able to decrypt the encrypted data after the app has shut down.

You will also want to save the public key if you wish to be able to encrypt new data with the same key after the app has shut down.

You would also need to add functionality to initialize the crypto functions with saved keys rather than generated ones.

The additional persistence management functions for keys are not in scope for this answer.

```
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.*;
import java.util.Base64;

class Crypto {
    private final PrivateKey privateKey;
    private final PublicKey publicKey;

    public Crypto() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
        generator.initialize(2048);
        KeyPair pair = generator.generateKeyPair();
        privateKey = pair.getPrivate();
        publicKey = pair.getPublic();
    }

    public String encrypt(String plainText) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        Cipher encryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        encryptCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
        byte[] encryptedBytes = encryptCipher.doFinal(
                plainText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
        );

        return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encryptedBytes);
    }

    public String decrypt(String cipherText) throws NoSuchPaddingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
        Cipher decryptCipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
        decryptCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, privateKey);
        byte[] encryptedBytes = decryptCipher.doFinal(
                Base64.getDecoder().decode(cipherText.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8))
        );

        return new String(encryptedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}
```

*EncryptApp.java*

Encrypts plain text in a text area using the crypto functions (RSA public key).

Decrypts cipher text in a text area using the crypto functions (RSA private key).

For display, the cipher text is base 64 encoded.

Using file handling, you can adapt this solution to persist the plain text and cipher text.  This persistence is out of the scope of this answer.

The UI is coded inline in the application in order not to complicate the solution, but the UI can be defined in CSS and FXML and UI binding and action handling moved to an FXML controller if desired.

```
import javafx.application.*;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class EncryptApp extends Application {

    private static final String SAMPLE_TEXT = """
            There once was a man from Nantucket,
            Who kept all his cash in a bucket.
            But his daughter, named Nan,
            Ran away with a man,
            And as for the bucket, Nantucket.
            """;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        final Crypto crypto;
        try {
             crypto = new Crypto();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Unable to initialize crypto functions");
            e.printStackTrace();
            Platform.exit();
            return;
        }

        TextArea plainTextArea = new TextArea(SAMPLE_TEXT);
        plainTextArea.setStyle("-fx-font-family: monospace;");

        Button encryptButton = new Button("Encrypt");

        Button clearButton = new Button("Clear");
        clearButton.setOnAction(e -> plainTextArea.clear());
        clearButton.disableProperty().bind(
                plainTextArea.textProperty().isEmpty()
        );

        VBox encryptSection = new VBox(10,
                new HBox(10, encryptButton, clearButton),
                plainTextArea
        );

        TextArea cipherTextArea = new TextArea();
        cipherTextArea.setStyle("-fx-font-family: monospace;");
        cipherTextArea.setEditable(false);
        cipherTextArea.setWrapText(true);

        Button decryptButton = new Button("Decrypt");
        decryptButton.disableProperty().bind(
                cipherTextArea.textProperty().isEmpty()
        );

        VBox decryptSection = new VBox(10, decryptButton, cipherTextArea);

        encryptButton.setOnAction(e ->
                encrypt(crypto, plainTextArea, cipherTextArea)
        );

        decryptButton.setOnAction(e ->
                decrypt(crypto, plainTextArea, cipherTextArea)
        );

        HBox layout = new HBox(
                10,
                encryptSection,
                decryptSection
        );
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));

        stage.setScene(new Scene(layout));
        stage.show();
    }

    private static void decrypt(Crypto crypto, TextArea plainTextArea, TextArea cipherTextArea) {
        try {
            plainTextArea.setText(
                    crypto.decrypt(cipherTextArea.getText())
            );
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String msg = "Unable to decrypt cipher text";
            plainTextArea.setText(msg);
            System.err.println(msg);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void encrypt(Crypto crypto, TextArea plainTextArea, TextArea cipherTextArea) {
        try {
            cipherTextArea.setText(
                    crypto.encrypt(plainTextArea.getText())
            );
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            String msg = "Unable to encrypt plain text";
            cipherTextArea.setText(msg);
            System.err.println(msg);
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

*module-info.java*

The module-info.java requires `jdk.crypto.cryptoki`, which provides the sun crypto provider for the RSA algorithms.  That will already be in a standard JDK distribution.  But, if you jlink this application, by default, it will only link the minimum modules it thinks it needs and the linker won't know to include the sun crypto provider.  That is why the cryptoki module is explicitly required.

```
module com.example.fxencrypt {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires jdk.crypto.cryptoki;
    exports com.example.fxencrypt;
}
```

Comment: *What do you want to achieve? If you want to create a signature...* (@Topaco)
*Yes, I want to create a digital signature* (OP)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that comment, perhaps I should not have answered. The original question was about encryption, not signing.  It isn’t clear to me that the poster understood the difference between signing and encryption. So I am not sure which they really want to achieve, even though the comment states that it is signing.  This answer addresses the question (well some part of it, not the entire thing), rather than the comment.